# Show only the requested forms using JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

As the image below illustrates, I have two forms and two buttons. Currently all the forms are visible.

How can I only show the requested form "according to the option they have selected (from the blue buttons on the top)"?

[image]

So, if the user clicked on the "send an invite" button, the sent an invite form will appear and the blue buttons will disappear "you can go back by clicking the back button".

**Is it possible to use dynamic ID dedication using JS to achieve this? as I will have more than 2 options on some pages etc...** For example, give the `<a class="button button-box"><p>Send an invite</p></a>` an id "#send-and-invite-form", it will then find the form that has that ID and show it. Then hide the div that contains those boxes until clicked back.

Here is a simplified HTML structure:

```
<div>
                <a class="button button-box"><p>Send an invite</p></a>
                <a class="button button-box"><p>Add manually</p></a>
            </div>

            <form data-parsley-validate>
                <fieldset>
                    <div>
                        <input name="" type="email" placeholder="Email address" required>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
                <div class="dialog-buttons">
                    <button class="button-green" type="submit">Submit</button>
                    <a>Back</a>
                </div>
            </form>

            <form data-parsley-validate>
                <fieldset>
                    <div>
                        <input name="" type="email" placeholder="Email address" required>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
                <div class="dialog-buttons">
                    <button class="button-green" type="submit">Submit</button>
                    <a>Back</a>
                </div>
            </form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep both the forms `hidden` at first and give a ID to each `<a>` and also to the `<form>`

Then

```
$("#id-of-btn1").click(function(){
   $("#form-1").toggle();
});
```

and

```
$("#id-of-btn2").click(function(){
   $("#form-2").toggle();
});
```

EDIT:
This could be a solution to make it completely independent of ID/Classes.

If you give a class to div containing all the `<a>` then

```
$(".class-of-div a").click(function(){
     var t=$(this).index();
     $("body").find("form").hide();
     $("body").find("form:eq("+t+")").toggle();
});
```

This will work for corresponding `<a>` and `<form>` only,so make sure that you have them in order.

Comment: Sounds the way to go, but I have few of those forms and on some I have more options than 2, is there a way to dynamically achieve this? otherwise I will be duplicating the snippet over and over..

Comment: Are number of forms always same as the  number of `<a>` @Leo

Comment: I think so, if we can make it fixable that is even better, but yea I guess.

Comment: @Leo What i mean is that number of `<a>` and `<form>` tags same and are ordered right way? Like First tag has to show the first form and so on,,

Comment: Yes, would it matter?

Comment: @Leo Just check the Edit and see if it helps!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81192/discussion-between-leo-and-varun).

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with the help of [:target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Atarget) pseudo selector. This is pure CSS solution:

```css
form {
    display: none;
}
form:target {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div> <a class="button button-box" href="#send-and-invite-form"><p>Send an invite</p></a>
 <a class="button button-box" href="#add-manually"><p>Add manually</p></a>

</div>
<form id="send-and-invite-form" data-parsley-validate>
    Invite
    <fieldset>
        <div>
            <input name="" type="email" placeholder="Email address" required />
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    <div class="dialog-buttons">
        <button class="button-green" type="submit">Submit</button> <a>Back</a>

    </div>
</form>

<form id="add-manually" data-parsley-validate>
    Manually
    <fieldset>
        <div>
            <input name="" type="email" placeholder="Email address" required />
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    <div class="dialog-buttons">
        <button class="button-green" type="submit">Submit</button> <a>Back</a>
    </div>
</form>
```

It is also possible to have default tag preselected, however it requires changing order of forms and using tricky selector:

```
form, form:target ~ #send-and-invite-form {
    display: none;
}
#send-and-invite-form, form:target {
    display: block;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/dfsq/5633tu4c/

Answer (score 0):

```
.show{display:block;}
.hide{display:none;}

 <a class="button button-box" id="lnkInvite" ><p>Send an invite</p></a>
 <a class="button button-box" id="lnkManually"><p>Add manually</p></a>

<form data-parsley-validate class="hide">Send an Invite Form</form>
<form data-parsley-validate class="hide">Add manually form</form>


<script type="text\javascript">

$().ready(function(){

$("#lnkInvite").click(function(){
       /*Toggle the show hide css class*/
});

$("#lnkManually").click(function(){
  /*Toggle the show hide css class*/
});

});


</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Simmple solution using js and style attributes.

<html>
        <head>
        <script>
        function showhide1(){
        document.getElementById("form1").style.display='block';
        document.getElementById("form2").style.display='none';
        }

        function showhide2(){
        document.getElementById("form2").style.display='block';
        document.getElementById("form1").style.display='none';
        }
        </script>
        </head>
        <body>
        <div>
                        <a class="button button-box" onclick="showhide1()"><p>Send an invite</p></a>
                        <a class="button button-box" onclick="showhide2()"><p>Add manually</p></a>
                    </div>

                    <form data-parsley-validate id="form1" >
                        <fieldset>
                            <div>
                                <input name="" type="email" placeholder="Email address1" required>
                            </div>
                        </fieldset>
                        <div class="dialog-buttons">
                            <button class="button-green" type="submit">Submit</button>
                            <a>Back</a>
                        </div>
                    </form>

                    <form data-parsley-validate id="form2">
                        <fieldset>
                            <div>
                                <input name="" type="email" placeholder="Email address" required>
                            </div>
                        </fieldset>
                        <div class="dialog-buttons">
                            <button class="button-green" type="submit">Submit</button>
                            <a>Back</a>
                        </div>
                    </form> 

                    <script>

                    document.getElementById("form2").style.display='none';
                    document.getElementById("form1").style.display='none';
                    </script>       
                    </body>
                    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep both forms hidden until the button for each is clicked.  Clicking the respective button will show the required form AND hide the button.  Click back hides the form and shows the button again.

I implemented for the invite section.  You will have to implement for the manual as well, but hopefully this points you in the right direction.  Also, I skipped the jQuery, but obviously this is your choice.

CSS

```
  .hidden{
    display: none;
    }
```

HTML

```
<div> <a id="inviteButton" class="button button-box"><p>Send an invite</p></a></div>
<form id="inviteForm" class="hidden">
    <fieldset>
        <div>
            <input name="" type="email" placeholder="Email address" required>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    <div class="dialog-buttons">
    <button class="button-green" type="submit">Submit</button> <a id="backButtonInvite">Back</a></div>
</form>
```

Javascript

```
var inviteButton = document.querySelector("#inviteButton");
var inviteForm = document.querySelector("#inviteForm");
var backButtonInvite = document.querySelector("#backButtonInvite");

inviteButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
    inviteForm.classList.toggle("hidden");
    this.classList.toggle("hidden");
});

backButtonInvite.addEventListener("click", function () {
    inviteForm.classList.toggle("hidden");
    inviteButton.classList.toggle("hidden");
});
```

Here is [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L1ze5fjf/).